# Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets

Tags: qt

I am new with qt5 and have installed from scratch using this tutorial here:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/qt5.html

Qt5 is installed in /opt/qt5/qt-5.4.1.

I have also done `sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev`.

However, when I tried to include webkitwidgets in my .pro file, the error is returned: `Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets`

Here is a snippet of my .pro:

```
QT       += core gui

QT += widgets webkitwidgets

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/lib/eigen-eigen-10219c95fe65 \
               /opt/qt5/qt-5.4.1/lib
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: That looks good.  Can you confirm that the libraries are actually there?  It's been ages since I've had this problem, and had it w/ another module.  I assume this is error is when you run qmake?  Might you have an old version lingering around?  Can you do 'which qmake' and make sure you're pulling in the right one?  It should be under /opt/qt5/qt-5.4.1/bin

Comment: I did 'which qmake' and got this in return: '/usr/bin/qmake'

Comment: Can you do 'qmake --version' to confirm the version, and also do 'find / -name "qmake" -print' and see if there are multiple versions on your system.  Possible you have an old (non-modular) Qt install, which is what /usr/bin/qmake is pointing to.

Comment: 'qmake --version' gives:
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: Those are definitely different versions.  Sounds like you're running qmake 5.2.1 (which sounds like it doesn't have qtwebkit enabled).  You should have a version of qmake under /opt/qt5/qt-5.4.1/bin (or somewhere near there).  When you find it, call it on your project file and see if the error persists.  If it doesn't, that's the problem and you just need to sort out your path.

Comment: A while back I needed 32-bit and 64-bit versions, so I just make symbolic links in my homedir, an always called ~/qmake64 or ~/qmake32.  Was a little irksome at first but I got used to it.

Comment: It shows :
'QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'

Comment: Right, but you said that you installed version qt-5.4.1 in /opt, right?  How many files do you get on your system when you do "sudo find / -name "qmake" -print"?  You should have at least one in your Qt target directory, which is  /opt/qt5/qt-5.4.1, based on your original topic.    If I was a gambling man, I'd say the one under /usr/lib came w/ your system.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I messed up with some bash files of my ubuntu and could not start it. 

I just modified 'qtchooser.conf'. 'qmake --version' is now giving:
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.4.1 in /opt/qt-5.4.1/lib

and 'sudo find / -name "qmake" -print' gives:
/usr/bin/qmake
/usr/share/qtcreator/templates/wizards/plaincppapp/qmake
/usr/share/qtcreator/templates/wizards/plaincapp/qmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake
/opt/qt-5.4.1/bin/qmake
/opt/qt-5.4.1/qtWebKitWidgets/Tools/qmake

Comment: But I still get the same error: 
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets

Comment: I've never tried qtchooser.  Can you 1) try invoking that version directly to make sure?  IE, /opt/qt-5.4.1/bin/qmake /path/to/project.pro and see if it remains.  If not, are you sure you did an install that install all the modules?  Are the headers there in the include directory?